# Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains NaN in property

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am making a web app that allows the user to grow a tree. When the user fertilizes the tree, the attribute "fertilizer" should increment. However, the app keeps giving me the error because it has decided that "fertilizer" is undefined.

The update score function looks like:

```
function updateScore(){
    if (usr!=null){
        var tree = $firebase(new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/trees/"+usr.treeid));
        var usrTree = tree.$asObject();
        var data = null;
        if (typeof usrTree.data !== 'undefined'){
            data = usrTree.data;
        }
        console.log(usrTree);
        console.log(usrTree.$id);
        console.log(usrTree.uid);
        console.log(usrTree.fertilizer);
        tree.$update({fertilizer: usrTree.fertilizer+1});
        }
    }
}
```

So the console gives these results:

```
e {$$conf: Object, $id: "-JcDm0UlYVGFfFAX0GSf", $priority: null, $save: function, $remove: function…}
$$conf: Object
$id: "-JcDm0UlYVGFfFAX0GSf"
$priority: null
fertilizer: 0
level: 0
pesticide: 0
sunshine: 0
uid: "simplelogin:6"
water: 0
__proto__: Object

-JcDm0UlYVGFfFAX0GSf

undefined

undefined
```

I believe the first one is the `usrTree` object, the second one is the `$id` and the third and the fourth should be `uid` and `fertilizer` but are caught undefined. However, in the `usrTree` object, `uid`and `fertilizer` do show up as defined and they exist in firebase forge:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?? What should I do to update the data??

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I need to use $loaded. I changed the code to the following and it works now.

```
var tree = $firebase(FirebaseRef.child("trees").child(usr.treeid));
var usrTree = tree.$asObject();
usrTree.$loaded().then(function() {
    tree.$update({fertilizer: usrTree.fertilizer + 1});
}
```

Comment: You will also want to use a [transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) here to ensure concurrent updates are all tallied correctly.