# Getting value from firebase returns error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

### **Problem**

With a social media app created by React Native I am trying to use a snapshot function to get data off of my firebase server, then add 1 to that value, then update that value on the server. The code I am doing that with is:

```
    this.setState({
      comments: firebase.database().ref('posts/'+this.state.passKey).once('value', function(snapshot) {snapshot.val().comments}) 
        })

    firebase.database().ref('posts').child(this.state.passKey).update({ 
      comments: this.state.comments+1
        })
```

When I run this code though, I get an error, saying:

```
Reference.update failed: 
First argument contains NaN in property 'posts.randompostkey.comments'
```

### **My Server**

[image: firebase server]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to properly synchronize access to the data: first ensure that everything is loaded, only then update the score.

Look at this **[`solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266114/error-firebase-update-failed-first-argument-contains-nan-in-property)**

Comment: did I do this right? It still said undefined. this.state.comments.$loaded().then(function() {
       firebase.database().ref('posts').child(this.state.passKey).update({ newestComment: 'Comment: ' + this.state.commentInput,
       comments: parseInt(this.state.comments)+1
     })})

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a **[transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)**.

```
postRef.transaction(function (post) {
            if (post) {
                    post.commentCount++;
                }    
            }
            return post;
        });
```

This way you can get your data, update the value and then post it back in a secure way, ensuring it is not being updated simultaneously by someone else

Answer (score 0):

I could not find official documentation on the topic, but it seems to me that Firebase refuses to store values of `NaN` and `undefined`.
Be sure not to send NaN values to Firebase.